# Hi. I got stuck in while executing the below r code to replace one column value with another

Tags: r

> I want to replace the value of the amount column with 50% of limit value, in case the amount is more than the limit.

```
cust_spend_trans[cust_spend_trans$Amount > cust_spend_trans$Limit, ] = (0.5*cust_spend_trans$Limit)
```

This gave me an error.

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cust_spend_trans$Amount > cust_spend_trans$Limit,  : 
  replacement has 1500 items, need 6070
```

Comment: `cust_spend_trans[cust_spend_trans$Amount > cust_spend_trans$Limit, ]` reflects a portion of the data, not all of the rows. `cust_spend_trans$Limit` reflects all of the rows. Further, the first reflects all columns, and the latter reflects just one column.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You code is trying to assign to *all columns* because you use `data[some_rows, ] = ...`. Instead you need `data[some_rows, "Amount"] = ...`
to specify which column you are assigning values to:

```
cust_spend_trans[cust_spend_trans$Amount > cust_spend_trans$Limit, "Amount"] = (0.5*cust_spend_trans$Limit)
```

Alternately, get rid of the comma inside `[` and put
`$Amount` at the start, so the assignment is to a subset of the column vector `data$Amount`

```
cust_spend_trans$Amount[cust_spend_trans$Amount > cust_spend_trans$Limit] = (0.5*cust_spend_trans$Limit)
```